# Member uploaded images

Tags: users

I'm considering using Craft for a new site. One requirement will be allowing members to upload and manage images. With Craft, can I set a size requirement for member uploaded images? So for example, if I only wanted to allow 400x400 image size to be uploaded, could I lock it down so that any image smaller or larger will just give an error?

If that's not possible, is there a way to resize/crop a large image down to the correct size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ad {author.username} to the file upload field, that way their files will always be in the folder of the user.

With assets you can define scale sizes which works way better then forcing a fixed size. It doesn't stop someone from uploading a 36 Mp image though. As far as I know it's impossible to check the canvas size before upload.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only thing I worry about with not being able to check size is that for the design to work and not break, I need them to be, say, 400x400 and someone uploads a 75x75. Thing are going to look bad. I guess there's where a flagging feature or something might have to come into play. not sure.

Comment: That should be possible after upload anyway. With the entry form you can upload files,the return page could check the size and produce a warning if it's to small.